# Sequelize subquery in from clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using POSTGRESQL with sequelize.js and would really like to execute a query which looks like this

```
SELECT "CT_Foo"."cola", "CT_Foo"."colb", "CT_Foo"."colc", 
  "CT_Foo"."cold", "CT_Foo"."cole", "CT_Foo"."colf",
  COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT "CT_BAR"."cola", "CT_BAR"."colb", "CT_BAR"."colc", 
      "CT_BAR"."cold", "CT_BAR"."cole", "CT_BAR"."colf", 
      "CT_BAR"."colg"
    FROM public."Customers" AS "CT_BAR"
    WHERE ("CT_BAR"."colf" IN ('SOMEID') AND "CT_BAR"."colg" ? 
          'date')
) AS "CT_Foo"  
WHERE ("CT_Foo"."colf" IN ('SOMEID'))
GROUP BY "CT_Foo"."cola", "CT_Foo"."colb", "CT_Foo"."colc", 
  "CT_Foo"."cold", "CT_Foo"."cole", "CT_Foo"."colf"
```

Columns A-F are text and G is JSONB

Basically the reason why I am doing this is because I need to group on columns A-F with a query on column F and if something exists in the JSONB in column G, I do not wish to include column G in the grouping, because it's JSON and I'm checking for the existence of a date... This seems a simple way to do this.  I know postgresql has CTE's but sequelize does not support them. I believe another name for this is "Derived Tables"

I can form a query normally, but cannot get the subquery into the FROM clause.

Any idea on how todo this or get the same result?